# where to install filebeat in ubuntu 18.04 and How to configure logstash to fetch logs in logfiles

Tags: elastic-stack

I need help on the following,

- Where to install filebeat in ubuntu 18.04 and How to configure logstash to fetch logs in logfiles
- how to parse the IPs(intrusion Prevention logs using logstash grok filter?

Comment: Congrats on your first post! Regarding your first question - did you search online? It would be more beneficial for you to show your troubleshooting efforts for these questions.

Comment: If you don't have filebeat you can check this link >> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-installation-configuration.html

or if you already filebeat type below command
whereis filebeat